# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

Okay, I know there are a lot of threads like this, but I've tried all the solutions in those, and they didn't work. So...
I've been trying to upgrade my packages using sudo apt-get upgrade -f
and every time, I've been getting this error message:

```
 $ sudo apt-get upgrade -f
 gnome-keyring iputils-ping libaacs0 libaccountsservice0 libgbm1
libgcr-base-3-1 libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring0
libgnutls-openssl27 libgnutls26 libio-socket-ssl-perl libldb1 libmtp-runtime
libmtp9 libneon27-gnutls libnih-dbus1 libnih1 libnm-glib4 libnm-util2
libpolkit-backend-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libsmbclient libssh2-1
libsystemd-journal0 ntfs-3g python-ldb python-samba python3-pycurl
resolvconf samba-common samba-common-bin samba-libs smbclient sysv-rc
telepathy-gabble telepathy-salut udisks2 unattended-upgrades util-linux
uuid-runtime
53 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 359 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/18.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 21.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 164580 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../util-linux_2.25.2-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking util-linux (2.25.2-6) over (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Setting up util-linux (2.25.2-6) ...
update-rc.d: warning: default start runlevel arguments (2 3 4 5) do not match hwclock.sh Default-Start values (S)
update-rc.d: warning: default stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not     match hwclock.sh Default-Stop values (0 6)
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
(Reading database ... 164696 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../plymouth_0.9.0-9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking plymouth (0.9.0-9) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/plymouth_0.9.0-9_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libply-splash-    graphics.so.2.1.0', which is also in package libplymouth2:amd64 0.8.8-    0ubuntu17.1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/plymouth_0.9.0-9_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using vivid (because you have [plymouth](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=plymouth&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) 0.9), but you have the libplymouth2 package from trusty (because trusty is the most recent release that ships [libplymouth2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libplymouth2&searchon=names)).

Remove it:

```
sudo apt purge libplymouth2
```

Then dpkg should no longer complain.

Comment: I can't purge libplymouth2: